# Pipe between two console applications?

Tags: c++, windows, pipe

How can I pipe between two separate console application running in different console windows?

e.g. I would like to do something similar to:

```
ffmpeg -i 0.flv -vcodec mpeg4 -f asf -s cif - | vlc -
```

However, I would like to do this from two separate windows, which doesn't work, I guess this is because standard out is local to cmd windows.

cmd window 1:

```
ffmpeg -i 0.flv -vcodec mpeg4 -f asf -s cif -
```

cmd window 2:

```
vlc -
```

Is there any way to programmatically achieve this? What exactly does `|` do behind the scenes?

Comment: If you tell us what you want to achieve with this exactly it might be easier to suggest a solution.

Comment: Pretty obvious he's trying to direct ffmpeg output to the input of VLC I think? :)

Comment: Yes, but the question is how to do this in 2 separate windows. Why in 2 windows? if he wants to follow the status reports from both programs (via STDERR), there might be other solutions to this (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What cmd does is connect the stdout of the first process to the stdin of the second process, you can do this programmatically. For an example see the following SO post:

[How does one setup a pipe between two child processes in Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310645/how-does-one-setup-a-pipe-between-two-child-processes-in-win32)

If you want to see the status output from both programs (STDERR), you can redirect this to another file or read it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way.  | pipes the output of one command into the stdin of another process.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing two wrapper processes that call the other processes and use named pipes to redirect data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365590(v=vs.85).aspx